# Proving well ordering principle from PMI (PCI) from peano axioms

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, order-theory, peano-axioms, well-orders

Axiomatically, set $\mathbb{N}$ is constructed via injective function $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and an element $1\in\mathbb{N}$ and we have that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:s(n)\neq1$. Together with this, we are given the axiom of mathematical induction, that is:

> **Axiom (PMI):** Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ satisfy following properties:
>   $$1\in S\tag{i}$$
>   $$n\in S\Rightarrow s(n)\in S\tag{ii}$$
>   then $S=\mathbb{N}$.

Now, in order to talk about *well ordering*, we should define the ordering we wish to prove is *well* on $\mathbb{N}$. We define addition:

> **Definition (addition):** $+\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$
>   $$a+1=s(a)\tag{iii}$$
>   $$a+s(b)=s(a+b)\tag{iv}$$

Then, we define strict order on $\mathbb{N}$ by:

> **Definition (ordering):**
>   $$a<b\Leftrightarrow \exists x\in\mathbb{N}:a+x=b\tag{v}$$
>   $$a\leq b\Leftrightarrow a<b\vee a=b\tag{vi}$$

It is straightforward to show that $\leq$ is total ordering. Now I wish to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered by $\leq$. So, I proceed by showing that PCI, also known as *Principle of Complete Induction*, holds.

> **Theorem (PCI):** Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ satisfy following properties:
>   $$1\in S\tag{vii}$$
>   $$\{1\ldots n\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}\Rightarrow s(n)\in S\tag{viii}$$
>   then $S=\mathbb{N}$.
>
> *Proof:* Proceed by induction. Because $1\in S$ it follows that $\{1\}\subseteq S$, so the base step holds. Now assume that $\{1\ldots n\}\subseteq S$. By (viii) $s(n)\in S$, thus $\{1\ldots,n,s(n)\}\subseteq S$. By PMI $S=\mathbb{N}$.

So far so good, now I show that this implies the WOP also known as *Well-ordering principle*.

> **Theorem(WOP):** $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered by $\leq$, equivallently, any nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has minimal element with respect to $\leq$.
>
> *Proof*: Assume there exists some $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $S$ has no minimal element. We show that $S$ is empty. Let $P(n)$ be predicate:
>   $$P(n):n\notin S$$
>   and proceed by PCI.
>   $P(1)$ holds, because (It is straightforward to show by induction) $\forall a\in\mathbb{N}:1\leq a$ and if $1\in S$ then $1$ is minimal element of $S$ which contradicts our assumption. So base step holds. Assume $\forall k\in \{1\ldots n\}:P(k)$. We wish to show that $P(s(n))$ holds. If $P(s(n))$ didn't hold, we would have that $s(n)\in S$ but in that case $s(n)$ is the smallest element in $S$, which is impossible. So by PCI it follows, that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:(n)$. But this shows that $S$ is empty. Thus any nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ must have minimal element.

Now, this looks very pretty, but as I red through this few times, i couldn't stop thinking about the set $\{1\ldots n\}$. In fact, what do we mean by set $\{1 \ldots n\}$? This is my "explanation": In fact
$$\{ 1\ldots n\}=\{1,s(1),s(s(1)),\ldots,s(s(s(\ldots s(1))))\}$$ So $n$ is some *finite* composition of $s$ applied to $1$. Trivially $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:n<s(n)$. Denote $M=\{1\ldots n\}$. Surely there exist some (unique) $n_1\in M$ such that $s(n_1)=n$, next, there is some $n_2\in M$ such that $n_1=s(n_2)$. By this process, we construct *finite* decreasing sequence $\{n_k\}$ ending at $1$ and we say that $\forall k\in M:k<s(n)$ by transitive property of the order. Most importantly, we are not able to construct any strict lesser number than $n$ itself by applying $s$ to it (because all these numbers are already in $M$) and thus (as said in the inductive step): $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}\setminus M:s(n)\leq k$ and thus $s(n)$ would be the least element in $S$.

If someone was thinking about the term *finite*, i can definite infiniteness as follows: A set $A$ is infinite if there is a bijection between its proper subset and the set itself. Then *finite* set is a set which is no infinite. But I am still unable to talk about *numbers* or *how many times* do i apply $s$. I could say that we apply $s$ to 1 $n$ times, but again, what is $n$? ... aand we run in circles.

Now, I am really curious about someone's opinion on that, because I see a very biig circular reasoning here. In fact, can i somehow rigorously show that $s(n)$ would be the least element in $S$ in the inductive step of the proof of WOP? Or am i actually completely wrong in something? Honestly, this argument seems weak to me and wouldn't persuade me. Thanks for any useful tips!

Comment: Why did you choose to not include 0 in the set of natural numbers?

Comment: Well, I was always taught that $\mathbb{N}$ begins with $1$ so i decided to go from $1$ but if i included $0$ the proofs and things would be pretty much simmilar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursively define $K(n) = \{1,2,.. n\}$

$= \{ 1, s(1), s(s(1)),.. s^{n-1}(1)\}. $

$K(1) = \{ 1 \};  K(s(n)) = K(n) \cup \{s(n)\}.$

Similarly, for any other $n$ applications of $s.$